# October installation

Tags: php, octobercms

I have installed october via console interface page. Backend works fine but UI gives error:

> The "Cms\Facades\Cms" extension is not enabled.
>   [image]

I couldn't figure out whats wrong with it.Could anybody help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Appears to be composer loading a too new version of Twig -

https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/2908#issuecomment-306431036

> fixed by opening composer.json in the root directory, adding to the require object this value:
>
> `"twig/twig": "1.33.*",`
>
> Then perform composer update to rectify the breaking package. This will be fixed in Build 420+ as we move to Twig 2.0. This upgrade won't occur for at least 1-2 months. Leaving this open until then.